# How can I write DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks from C# in java

Tags: java, c#, java-time, instant

I am trying to rewrite below two lines of code from C# into Java.

```
long ticks1970Onwards = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).Ticks;
 long newTs =    (DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - ticks1970Onwards)/10000;
```

I tried multiple ways , but I don't get the correct solution.

```
        ZonedDateTime dt1 = LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        ZonedDateTime dt2 = LocalDateTime.of(1901, 1, 1, 0, 0).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        Duration duration2 = Duration.between(dt2, dt1);
        System.out.printf("Duration = %s milliseconds.%n", duration2.getSeconds()*1000);
```

Comment: you can replace whole c# with `System.currentTimeMillis()` - this will give you number of milliseconds since 1970-1-1

Comment: @IłyaBursov Yes, if you have got somehting against object orientation, you can. The code using `Instant` or other classes from java.time is much more self-explanatory, though.

Answer (score 2):

### [`Instant#toEpochMilli`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli--)

Use it to convert [`Instant.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now--) to the number of milliseconds from the epoch of `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` where `Z` stands for `Zulu` time and represents `UTC`.

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        System.out.println(now.toEpochMilli());
    }
}
```

You can compare this result with that of the C# code at [C# PlayGround](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yUeYk7).

**Note:** Avoid specifying a timezone with the 3-letter abbreviation. A timezone should be specified with a name in the format, *Region/City* e.g. `ZoneId.of("Europe/London")`. With this convention, the `ZoneId` for `UTC` can be specified with `ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC")`. A timezone specified in terms of `UTC[+/-]Offset` can be specified as `Etc/GMT[+/-]Offset` e.g. `ZoneId.of("Etc/GMT+1")`, `ZoneId.of("Etc/GMT+1")` etc.

There are some exceptional cases as well e.g. to specify the timezone of `Turkey`, you can specify

```
ZoneId.of("Turkey")
```

However, it is recommended ([Thanks to Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65534226/how-can-i-write-datetime-utcnow-ticks-from-c-sharp-in-java/65534483#comment116265303_65534483)) to use the same pattern as described above i.e. the recommended way of representing the timezone of Turkey is:

```
ZoneId.of("Asia/Istanbul")
```

or

```
ZoneId.of("Europe/Istanbul")
```

Probably, `Istanbul` being referred with two regions/continents is the reason why it is still returned by `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

The following code will give you all the available `ZoneId`s:

```
// Get the set of all time zone IDs.
Set<String> allZones = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
```

Comment: The time zone ID `Turkey` is deprecated. The recommended ones for Turkey are `Asia/Istanbul` and `Europe/Istanbul` (because Istanbul is the largest city of Turkey and is distributed with the old part in Europe and the now larger part in Asia).

Comment: Thanks, @OleV.V. for the important information about `Turkey`. Probably, `Istanbul` being referred with two regions/continents is the reason why it is still returned by `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

Comment: `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()` generally returns a lot of deprecated IDs without any marking that they are deprecated. Mentioning just a few: Africa/Asmera, America/Buenos_Aires, America/Godthab, America/Knox_IN, Asia/Calcutta, Australia/LHI, Brazil/Acre, Canada/Atlantic, CET, CST6CDT, Cuba, Etc/Greenwich, GB, MET, NZ-CHAT. I am using [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (itself not up to date) for checking which are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); // Clear the millis part. Silly API. 
calendar.set(2010, 8, 14, 0, 0, 0); // Note that months are 0-based 
Date date = calendar.getTime(); 
long millis = date.getTime(); // Millis since Unix epoch
```

1. example

import java.util.*;

public class Test {

```
private static final long TICKS_AT_EPOCH = 621355968000000000L; 
private static final long TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND = 10000; 

public static void main(String[] args) { 
 long ticks = 634200192000000000L; 

 Date date = new Date((ticks - TICKS_AT_EPOCH)/TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND); 
 System.out.println(date); 

 TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"); 
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(utc); 
 calendar.setTime(date); 
 System.out.println(calendar); 
}
```

}

2. example

   import java.util.Calendar;
   import java.util.Date;

   public class DateHelper {

   ```
    private static final long TICKS_AT_EPOCH = 621355968000000000L; 
    private static final long TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND = 10000; 

    public static long getUTCTicks(Date date){ 

     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
     calendar.setTime(date); 

     return (calendar.getTimeInMillis() * TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND) + TICKS_AT_EPOCH; 

    } 

    public static Date getDate(long UTCTicks){ 

     return new Date((UTCTicks - TICKS_AT_EPOCH)/TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND); 

    }
   ```

Comment: The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. This is the outdated answer, though. I recommend you don’t use `Date`, `TimeZone` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Just as the question does.